# Using Glacier as back end for web crawling

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-glacier

I will be doing a crawl of several million URLs from EC2 over a few months and I am thinking about where I ought to store this data.  My eventual goal is to analyze it, but the analysis might not be immediate (even though I would like to crawl it now for other reasons) and I may want to eventually transfer a copy of the data out for storage on a local device I have.  I estimate the data will be around 5TB.

My question: I am considering using Glacier for this, with the idea that I will run a multithreaded crawler that stores the crawled pages locally (on EB) and then use a separate thread that combines, compresses, and shuttles that data to Glacier.  I know transfer speeds on Glacier are not necessarily good, but since there is no online element of this process, it would seem feasible (esp since I could always increase the size of my local EBS volume in case I'm crawling faster than I can store to Glacier).

Is there a flaw in my approach or can anyone suggest a more cost-effective, reliable way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Glacier is fundamentally a long-term-archiving tool, with an eye to regulatory compliance (e.g, "you must maintain archives of XYZ data for at least N years"). Retrieving data from it is a slow, complex, and sometimes expensive process — it is probably not the right tool for the job unless you are storing a lot of data which you are unlikely to retrieve.

Answer (score 3):

Redshift seems more relevant than Glacier. Glacier is all about freeze / thaw and you'll have to move the data prior to doing any analysis.

Redshift is more about adding the data into a large, inexpensive, data warehouse and running queries over it.

Another option is to store the data in EBS and leave it there. When you're done with your crawling take a Snapshot to push the volume into S3 and decomission the volume and EC2 instance. Then when you're ready to do the analysis just create a volume from the snapshot.

The upside of this approach is that it's all file access (no formal data store) which may be easier for you.

Personally, I would probably push the data into Redshift. :-)

--
Chris

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful comments.  Not sure that Redshift is quite right for me (I wouldn't normally need a DW for this), but your post got me thinking about some of the other options, and I appreciate your comments about Glacier.

Answer (score 0):

If your analysis will not be immediate then you can adopt one of the following 2 approaches

Approach 1) Amazon EC2 crawler -> store in EBS disks - Move them frequently to Amazon S3-> archive regularly to glacier. You can store your last X days data in Amazon S3 and use it for adhoc processing as well.

Approach 2) Amazon EC2 crawler -> store in EBS disks - Move them frequently to Amazon Glacier.   Retrieve when needed and do the processing on EMR or other processing tools

If you need frequent analysis:

Approach 3) Amazon EC2 crawler -> store in EBS disks - Move them frequently to Amazon S3-> Analysis through EMR or other tools and store the processed results in S3/DB/MPP and move the raw files to glacier

Approach 4) if your data is structured, then Amazon EC2 crawler -> store in EBS disks and move them to Amazon RedShift and move the raw files to glacier

Additional tips:
If you can retrieve the data again(from source)then you can use ephemeral disks for your crawlers instead of EBS

Amazon has introduced Data pipeline service, check whether it fits your needs on data movement.